# subset stacked bars chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, apexcharts

I want to display data I have where series of data is subset of others.
I want to display it as stacked bar but not sure how to do it, everywhere I see is just series upon another.
basically what I try to achieve is that the blue bar will be on top of the red one but each bar's label will show the full data.
[image]

example of data would be:
30 people
16 like apples
8 like apples & oranges
etc...

example of how it should look (with the example data)
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use c3.js for the problem Visit : https://c3js.org/samples/chart_bar_stacked.html

Comment: it's like the stacked kind I don't want. am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://jsfiddle.net/matrixatp/48yc01e9/) is what you need. Simply set stacked to true in both axes:

```
options: {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{ stacked: true }],
    yAxes: [{ stacked: true }]
  }
}
```

If you don't receive your data from the back end in this structure you will need to do some changes before adding it to the chart.

.:EDIT:.
Updated fiddle

Comment: this is a normal stacked data, which is not what I'm looking for.
what I'm looking for is stacked but - instead of showing 2 potatoes it should show 6.
6 people like potatoes, and from them 4 like trains as well. (4 like both)

Comment: I see, I misunderstood your requirements. Can you post some sample data? I can update my answer after I know what I'm working with.

Comment: added a sketch for the example data of how I want it to look

Comment: Yes, I got what you need it to look like, but what is the structure of your object? Is it a list of people? What properties do they have?

Comment: 3 array (dataset), a bar is composed of the data found in all 3 arrays for a certain index.

Comment: Let me clarify: can you post the data you receive and want to add to the chart? For example `people = [{name: 'Peter', likes: ['apples', 'oranges']}, {name: 'John', likes: ['apples']}]`. This sample data should generate a bar that goes to 2 since both like apples, but also have a subset since 1 likes oranges, if I understand correctly. But what if a third person shows up and he likes only lemons?

Comment: that's irrelevant I know how to make these calculation my self. I just need a way to display it.